# Combo box 2 is not showing the values in output (php)

Tags: php

the cmbYL values are not showing in my output but the cmbCourse is working just fine, thank you in advance. This is the CmbYL code. I can't paste my whole table code because stack overflow is limiting me.

[this is the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGHAv.png)

```
<?php
            $course = "";
            if (isset($_SESSION['ses_cmbCourse'])) {
                if ($_SESSION['ses_cmbCourse']=='BSIT') {
                    echo "BS Information Technology";
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['ses_cmbCourse']=='BSCS') {
                    echo "BS Computer Science";
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['ses_cmbCourse']=='BSECE') {
                    echo "BS Electronics Engineering";
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['ses_cmbCourse']=='BSID') {
                    echo "BS Interior Design";
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['ses_cmbCourse']=='BSHRM') {
                    echo "BS Hotel and Restaurant Management";
                }
                else{
                    echo "BS Tourism Management";
                }
            }
            ?>

<?php
            $year = "";
            if (isset($_SESSION['ses_cmbYL'])) {
                if ($_SESSION['ses_cmbYL']=='1st') {
                    echo "1st yr";
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['ses_cmbYL']=='2nd') {
                    echo "2nd";
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['ses_cmbYL']=='3rd') {
                    echo "BS Electronics Engineering";
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['ses_cmbYL']=='4th') {
                    echo "4th";
                }
                else{
                    echo "5th yr";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: that means you haven't got $_SESSION['ses_cmbYL'] set so echo it and check

Comment: thank you! I'll try to look at it ><